# When and why did the black velvet yarmulke become the standard for some communities?

Tags: history, clothing, ashkenazi, kippa-yarmulka

[Ashkenazi yarmulkes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOzic.jpg) from around [200 years ago](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaom1.jpg) closely resemble the [Yerushalmi style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SemrG.jpg) - white knitted with a tassel on top.  Today, the vast majority of Chasidim and Yeshivish Jews seem to wear black velvet yarmulkes, with some notable exceptions.  When and why did this change take place?

Comment: I guess the question could be asked in reverse - when and how did Ashkenazi Yarmulkes start resembling today's Yerushalmi style ones (with links to photographs)?

Comment: Seth, how can the question be asked in reverse?

Comment: FYI, in “Teshuvah, A Guide for the Newly Observant Jew”, Adin Steinsaltz writes that because the male head covering is a not a matter of mitzvah, there are no requirements about how it should be made. As to the shape or materials there are no limitations. The various types of headgear are a matter of local or communal custom. Halakhically meaningless details can take on a certain significance so that various kinds of head covering can signify very specific things to both religious and non religious people.

Comment: @avi I assume Seth means that we might as well ask how it is that many Yerushalmim wear yarmulkes like those worn 200 years ago and never adopted the standard black velvet.

Comment: There is nothing "standard" about the black velvet.... Most Jews do not wear black velvet kippahs.

Comment: @avi (and AviD) the question specifies amongst whom it is the standard.

Comment: this obsession with what type of kipa you wear is strange and unproductive. (not making accusations just saying thos who have this obsession need to re-examine their priorities) many I have met seem to think they can judge your personality and your level of commitment based on the type of kipa you wear. This is wrong. No is no difference in any style of kipa. They all serve the same purpose which is to remind us that G-d is all around us and we should conduct ourselves properly as such. The best kipa for you depends on your personal preference and what you like to wear on your head.

Comment: @Yoel, your photos only deal with the styles worn in Eastern Europe. In western Europe, those who didn't wear the deckel (large round hat) typically wore a style somewhat similar to the Bukharan kippah, although typically monotone and silk.

Comment: The photos you provided depict the kippot of the Baal HaTanya and Rebbe Nachman of Breslov respectively. Both were Chasidic leaders. Do you think because two Chasidic leaders wore this style means everyone in Eastern Europe, or even all Europe, wore them?

Answer (score 13):

I heard Rabbi Berel Wein discussing that Rashi's headcovering (in the animated film made by Rabbi Wein) is red, maroon, and/or brown. The historical research shows those were men's colors for Jews in Rashi's time and place. Someone objected that it should be a black velvet yarmulka. Rabbi Wein replied that black happened in the 1400s as a result of a Church decree that colors were too happy for Jews, they should only wear black. Much later, some rabbis came along and said "I see the Jews wear black; that's nice, it's a sign of humility."

That doesn't completely answer the question, but it's probably a piece.

(Of course, Rabbi Wein's questioner replied, "oh um ... but you *still* should have made it a black velvet yarmulka!" Rabbi Wein: "What's next? Rashi with a shtreimel? When is it wrong to tell the historical truth?")

Comment: Well, as you may know, even [Moshe Rabenu wore a streiml](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MwbWv2oiuAs)...

Comment: 1400s doesn't make sense since the questioner is asking about the 1800s.

Comment: Chasidic bekeshes also used to be white and have also changed (not got dirty!)

Comment: Some chabadniks today wear dark red, brown or navy blue velvet kippas -- somewhat similar to the colors R' Wein mentioned.

Comment: In Eastern Europe, prior to the mid 18th century, it was common for the baalei battim to wear colourful clothes, but some rav paskened that it was problematic, as it attracted anti-semitic attacks

Answer (score 3):

One odd thought might be related to size?  As you knit a kippah it takes more effort as the outer rim gets larger and larger.  I asked my sister once to knit me one, but I have a big head and like a big kippah.  She did it once and refused after that saying it was so much work to do big ones.

Cloth kippahs have no major additional cost in effort (material is cheap) to make larger sizes.

I doubt this is a real answer, but something to consider.

Comment: In Israel, the larger knitted kippot are much more common than the smaller ones.  Especially amongst people who live in areas where there is a lot of manual labor. (they fall off less)

Comment: @avi Excellent points.  Also why I wanted larger ones.  But my experience with larger knit kippahs is that the thread is much thicker and thus much less effort to make larger.

Answer (score 3):

From this Google Books search you can see a few references in the mid- and late-19th century to Jews in Europe (including Polish Jews and a Jew from Italy) wearing black velvet kippas.

https://www.google.com/search?q=%22velvet+skull+cap%22+jew&biw=1138&bih=548&sa=X&ei=zsNzU5LRL4aaqAan2YHQDw&ved=0CCEQpwUoBA&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1700%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1899&tbm=bks#q=%22velvet+skull+cap%22+jew&start=0&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1700,cd_max:12/31/1899

I assume that they became popular because velvet appears formal and dressy, and would have looked good with formal black coats. But I have no real information on why the change took place.